# MySQL Server - Set max_allowed_packet value permanently

Tags: mysql, size, packet

I have a MySQL Server version 5.5.25 installed on CentOS server.
I've increased *max_allowed_packet* size to 32M in /etc/my.cnf file in order to store it permanently (`max_allowed_packet = 32M;`), then I've restarted server with */etc/init.d/mysqld restart*. The problem is that in PHPMyAdmin the value doesn't change. I tried to set variable from shell with `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 33554432;` (32 MB), but shell returns "0 rows affected".

Is it a bug of MySQL server? Or maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart Apache?

```
 service httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes, but value remains the same ._.

Comment: Oh, I feel an idiot... I had set value in my.cnf in the wrong point of the file (below [mysqld-safe] and not [mysqld]). What a shame. Thanks anyway for answers...